# Dynamic replacing content

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, plugins, css

I'm developing a one page website that has a product's catalogue.

These are the basic characteristics:

- one page website, with header, content and footer (HTML5/CSS3)
- changing content dynamically by loading the products catalogue and each section without loading the entire page
- deep linking

What's the best solution? plugins? jquery, ... ?!?!

The ideal solution was to have each content section in a separate page that would be dynamically loaded ondemand to the main page. That way I could have in each page a diferent design (including the possibility to apply jquery plugins), according to the content itself.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure what your asking... If your asking how best to implement this, you've already answered your own question by stating HTML5/CSS3 and jquery.

Comment: This is SO going to get down voted... I'd suggest looking into AJAX though.

Comment: The reason of the downvotes is not that it's posted on SO, but because the question's quality is to cry. There's no definite answer, because it's a very vague question. Please improve it.

Answer (score 0):

This question could solicit debate, however, you could do what you want with a standard $.ajax call in jquery or even a $.get call with a callback.  Such as

```
$.get("/link/to.php",function(data)
{
   $("#newcontent").html(data);
});
```

To bind it to a link use something similar to:

```
<a href="/path/to.php" data-remote="true">Link</a>
```

Then in your script use:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("a[data-remote]").bind("click",function()
     {
         event.preventDefault();
         $.get("/link/to.php",function(data)
         {
             $("#newcontent").html(data);
         });
     }
 });
```

Comment: thanks ...

i'm not familiar with jquery, but is it possible to load a page with jquery plugins into other page via jquery?

thanks

Comment: @user1463905 You can load an entire page into a div using JQuery's built in AJAX functions.  The above code would load to.php in any html tag with an id of newcontent.  If you wanted it to load in a div tag just use "div#newcontent instead.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the previous french answer.

From what I know, if the backend is done in Java, [GWT](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/) is a good solution, with the module "places and activities", you can easily set up a common portion of the web application and a dynamic portion changing according to the pages. This module also supports deep linking.

For a pure client side solution, the new javascript framework google [angularjs](http://angularjs.org) with the rooter module seems answer all your project's constraints. This framework is design for easilly make MVC components, it's can be an additional argument.
This framework is very young, it may be uninteresting to you a little Bencher of the framework to make sure it is string enough for your immediate and futures needs.

More generically I think you should you search about RIA javascript frameworks. May also be others than me will bring you more answers.

Hoping it may help.